# Can I put HTML into a variable?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Using the Sinatra library, I'm trying to condense two functions that display HTML code into a single function. Both these functions differ by only a small amount of HTML. 
Here's an example.

```
def make_start_page()
   <<EOS
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p> Hello </p>
      <img src="..." />
   </body>
   </html>
   EOS
end

def make_guess_page()
   <<EOS
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p> Something different </p>
      <a href="..." >1</a>
   </body>
   </html>
   EOS
end
```

In the Ruby function that will call these two functions, I was wondering if it is possible to take the small portion of HTML that differs and pass it to a single, condensed version of these two functions that will display the page.

```
def handle()
   if 1
      var = "<p> Hello </p>
      <img src="..." />"
   elsif 2
      var = "<p> Something different </p>
      <a href="..." >1</a>"
   make_start_guess_page(var)
end
```

Comment: The "DRY" concept, i.e. "Don't repeat yourself", is what you're talking about. It's better to refactor into one piece of code that understands the differences and conditionally substitutes what you need in a particular context so you don't have largely redundant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpolate variables in heredoc:

```
def make_start_page(var)
   <<EOS
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      #{var}
   </body>
   </html>
   EOS
end
```

For example.

Answer (score 1):

There no reason why you could not do that. However if you want to print it, you'll probably have to use functions like `String#html_safe` in rails, or `!=` in haml